# PHPMyAdmin forces to use ut8mb4 as default collation

Tags: mysql

After to updated PHPMyAdmin the default collation has been set to *utf8mb4_general_ci* instead the old default collation *utf8_general_ci*. As I do not have any need to use *utf8mb4_general_ci* I would like to restore *utf8_general_ci* as default.

Looking on my database configuration I have this:

```
default-character-set = utf8 
character-set-server  = utf8 
collation-server      = utf8_general_ci 
character_set_server   = utf8 
collation_server       = utf8_general_ci
```

Also I have added these lines to the file config.inc.php in PHPMyAdmin to try to make it work.

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf8_general_ci'; 
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

However, even when all is set to *utf8_general_ci* on the config files still I can see on the main page *utf8mb4_general_ci* as defaul Server connection collation. Is there something it could be done to set the collation to *utf8_general_ci* instead?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf8';
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

will have the effect of all statements to get the correct charset (notice that right value for "DefaultCharset" is "utf8") and collation, although on start page the "utf8mb4_general_ci" is displayed which might be a "by design" converted value feature in phpMyAdmin.